# Need help identifying bmx bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

I recently got a ton of bmx parts and 2 frames for free from someone on nextdoor. He left the parts at the end of driveway, so I couldn't ask any questions. I'm curious about this race frame he gave me. I put this mostly together from parts in the box. The decals have been removed, and there was only an Answer sticker on the bottom of the frame. I'm hoping the gusset on the headtube may help someone identify it for me [image]
[image]
![enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dvfq.jpg)[image]

Comment: Serial # format is T97*****

Comment: In searching, it looks VERY similar to a mid 90's Free Agent Limo. I was pretty excited, but after a close examination, it seems to be slightly different. Still looking. I tried to contact them to check the serial #, but they don't have a contact on their website.

Comment: Also looks similar to a mid 90s Redline RL440, but just not quite the same

Comment: Also looks like a Diamondback, but just not quite. Definitely 90s era, mid school

Comment: It's a super close match for the 97 RL 380 - but the gusset does not have the "RL" stamp https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/redline/29294

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can tell if a bike is good quality by the attention they paid to finishing it.

So, for example, and expensive bike has the welds ground off and sanded, so that the joins between the tubes look smooth. This also reduces the chance of rust getting in.

The chrome plating will also be higher quality and very shiny (and easy to polish as a result). If the chrome is tarnished and peeling, it's a sign of less attention being paid in the factory.

To me it just looks like a mass produced bike. Perhaps not bottom rung quality, but not the best either.

The weight test is another simple way to tell. Cheaper bikes can also double as boat anchors :)

Answer (score -1):

84-86 Schwinn predator .. I have one like it

Comment: If you have a photo to add, especially of the headtube gusseting the questioner mentioned and showed in their picture, it would be awesome (edit your answer to add it).  And I would vote this up if you do.

Comment: Not a Schwinn Predator. Here is a link the BMX Museum - none of them look like this frame. [84-86 Schwinn Predator](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/search?q=predator&year-start=1984&year-end=1986&company%5B%5D=20)